# Modifying Windows 10/11 alarms trough C# code

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, alarm

Is there any way that I could modify Windows 10/11 alarms trough code, and have them added to the Alarms & Clock app? If needed, I'm using UWP with C#. I know, it is quite a short question, but there's nothing more to it

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: This is not a type of question in which I have problems and need answers, I was just curious if it is possible to do such thing

Comment: @IKDev, currently there is no api for this,  I have answer detail below, do you have any updates or requirement ?

Answer (score 0):

> Modifying Windows 10/11 alarms trough C# code

Currently there is no such api could edit alarm with code, and there is no [uri scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-default-app) could use to launch alarm and add scheme also. If you do want this feature please feel free post your requirement with windows feedback hub app.